# How to place a mc above an embeded swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I am struggling to embed a swf in a flash movie so that it appears beneath a mc menubar.
The menu is in a mc on the main time line at the top layer.
The swf is embeded into a mc using the following  :

```
swapChildren(fullmc, swfbox1);
var myLoader1 :Loader = new Loader(); 
 swfbox1.addChild(myLoader1);
 var url1 :URLRequest = new URLRequest("26A.swf"); 
 myLoader1 .load(url1 );
 stop();
```

However whatever I do (even trying "swapChildren" ) the embeded swf always appears on top of the menu mc hiding it completely.
Im sure theres a simple reason. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks
Ed

Answer (score 0):

have you tried? sorry my bad, i wrote too fast , try this instead

```
//if fullmc holds the mc you want above
var mc:MovieClip = this.root as MovieClip;
mc.addChildAt( swfbox1 , 0 );
```

Comment: 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.display:MovieClip to an unrelated type Class.
1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:MovieClip.
However Im not quite sure where I should have placed your code, does it replace part of the embeding code above?
thanks